# Netezza, NodeJS and unixODBC interesting error

Tags: node.js, odbc, netezza, unixodbc

I've tested my DSN for Netezza with isql and it works fine. I also created a DSN for MySQL to test. If I use the MySQL DSN, in my nodejs file, it will connect and I can query the mysql database. But as soon as I try to use my Netezza DSN I get an interesting error.

Code:

```
db.open("DSN=NZSQL", function(err)
```

Error:

```
{ [Error: [unixODBC]敓癲牥愠摮漯⁲潰瑲愠瑴楲畢整⁳牡⁥浥瑰y]
  errors: [ { message: '[unixODBC]敓癲牥愠摮漯⁲潰瑲愠瑴楲畢整⁳牡⁥浥瑰y', state: '奈〰0' } ],
  error: '[node-odbc] SQL_ERROR',
  message: '[unixODBC]敓癲牥愠摮漯⁲潰瑲愠瑴楲畢整⁳牡⁥浥瑰y',
  state: '奈〰0' }
```

Yes you are seeing the correct way the error is printed. I have no idea why the error is printed in Asian characters. And I have no idea why I can't connect nodejs to Netezza. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks Stack!

Comment: Can you post the error message in English ?

Comment: That is the error message. I have no idea why it gets printed in Asian characters. Or why it won't connect to Netezza.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues. Firstly, you have an encoding mismatch between the connection and your program. The string "敓癲牥愠摮漯⁲潰瑲愠瑴楲畢整⁳牡⁥浥瑰y" decoded from UTF-16 to UTF-8 is "Server and/or port attributes are empty" -- which leads us nicely into your second issue.